# How to make all <div> blocks of different sizes share the same top boundary(margin)?

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
  .box
  {
   display : inline-block;
   padding : 10px;
  }
  
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="region">
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:40px; height:40px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:80px; height:80px; background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you run the code snippet, you'll see that all the blocks are aligned at the base (like kept on a flat surface). What needs to be modified in the CSS so that all the **div** tags are aligned at the upper boundary?

If my question isn't clear then try imagining rotating the output of this snippet by 180 degrees. That is how I want the output to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since they are `inline-block` just set their `vertical-align` to `top`

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="region">
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:40px; height:40px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:80px; height:80px; background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the `.box`

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;  
}
```

```html
<div class="region">
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:40px; height:40px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:80px; height:80px; background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="box" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:green"></div>
</div>
```